# Can you create a programming language with just one symbol?

Tags: brainfuck, esoteric-languages

Can you create a programming language with just one symbol like brainfuck.

Comment: https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary

Comment: It could be done, but it would be so inefficient it seems pointless. Do consider that Brainfuck, for all its simplicity, is very educational through its computation model.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it has been done before - see [Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary).

Basically it's a strange encoding of brainfuck. Treat each BF command as a number. The whole program is then also a number, created by concatenating the commands together (with an extra 1 at front, for unambiguous decoding). Convert the number to unary numeric system (aka the number of digits is your number) and you're done.

Note however the programs in this tend to be very large - a `cat` implemented in Unary is (according to the information on page) 56623 characters long.

[MGIFOS](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MGIFOS), [Lenguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage) and [Ellipsis](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ellipsis) follow the same principle. Note that e.g. a hello world in MGIFOS

> has more characters than particles in the observable universe

Then [Len(language,encoding)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Len(language,encoding)) extends this principle to any language.

Comment: LOL. My thought exactly. Godel Numbering is an alternative. Just to make things harder you understand!

Answer (score 1):

They are called [OISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer) One Instruction Set Compiler.
The first one know of is [Melzak's Arithmetic Machine (1961)](https://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CMB-1961-031-9), with the instruction:

```
z = x-y or jump if y>x
```

You also have Zero Instruction Set Computer, which are more like neural nets.

Not forgetting the amazing [FRACTRAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FRACTRAN) of Conway & Guy (1996), with no instruction but interprets a series of fractions (the program) in a Tuning complete way.